# PApplet error on IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, processing, kinect, openkinect

I am trying to use the Processing and OpenKinect library on IntelliJ to connect my Kinect to use it for hand detection, this code works on Processing 3 but for some reason when I put it up on IntelliJ, in proper format, I get this error:

> Usage: PApplet [options]  [sketch args] See the Javadoc
>   for PApplet for an explanation.

These are the two classes I am using.

**Main.java**

```
package lol.uk;

import processing.core.*;
//import org.openkinect.freenect.*;
import org.openkinect.processing.*;
import processing.core.PImage;
import processing.core.PVector;
//import processing.core.PImage;

public class Main extends PApplet {

    KinectTracker tracker;
    Kinect kinect;


    public void setup() {
        size(640, 520);
        kinect = new Kinect(this);
        tracker = new KinectTracker();
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(255);

        // Run the tracking analysis
        tracker.track();
        // Show the image
        tracker.display();

        // Let's draw the raw location
        PVector v1 = tracker.getPos();
        fill(50, 100, 250, 200);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(v1.x, v1.y, 20, 20);

        // Let's draw the "lerped" location
        PVector v2 = tracker.getLerpedPos();
        fill(100, 250, 50, 200);
        noStroke();
        ellipse(v2.x, v2.y, 20, 20);

        // Display some info
        int t = tracker.getThreshold();
        fill(0);
        text("threshold: " + t + "    " + "framerate: " + (frameRate) + "    " + "UP increase threshold, DOWN decrease threshold", 10, 500);
    }

    public void keyPressed() {
        int t = tracker.getThreshold();
        if (key == CODED) {
            if (keyCode == UP) {
                t += 5;
                tracker.setThreshold(t);
            } else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
                t -= 5;
                tracker.setThreshold(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**KinectTracker.java**

```
package lol.uk;

import org.openkinect.processing.Kinect;
import processing.core.*;
import processing.core.PImage;
import processing.core.PVector;

public class KinectTracker extends PApplet {
    // Depth threshold
    int threshold = 500;

    Kinect kinect;

    // Raw location
    PVector loc;

    // Interpolated location
    PVector lerpedLoc;

    // Depth data
    int[] depth;

    // What we'll show the user
    PImage display;

    KinectTracker() {
        // This is an awkard use of a global variable here
        // But doing it this way for simplicity
        kinect.initDepth();
        kinect.enableMirror(true);
        // Make a blank image
        display = createImage(kinect.width, kinect.height, RGB);
        // Set up the vectors
        loc = new PVector(0, 0);
        lerpedLoc = new PVector(0, 0);
    }

    public void track() {
        // Get the raw depth as array of integers
        depth = kinect.getRawDepth();

        // Being overly cautious here
        if (depth == null) return;

        float sumX = 0;
        float sumY = 0;
        float count = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < kinect.width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < kinect.height; y++) {

                int offset =  x + y*kinect.width;
                // Grabbing the raw depth
                int rawDepth = depth[offset];

                // Testing against threshold
                if (rawDepth < threshold) {
                    sumX += x;
                    sumY += y;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        // As long as we found something
        if (count != 0) {
            loc = new PVector(sumX/count, sumY/count);
        }

        // Interpolating the location, doing it arbitrarily for now
        lerpedLoc.x = PApplet.lerp(lerpedLoc.x, loc.x, 0.3f);
        lerpedLoc.y = PApplet.lerp(lerpedLoc.y, loc.y, 0.3f);
    }

    PVector getLerpedPos() {
        return lerpedLoc;
    }

    PVector getPos() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void display() {
        PImage img = kinect.getDepthImage();

        // Being overly cautious here
        if (depth == null || img == null) return;

        // Going to rewrite the depth image to show which pixels are in threshold
        // A lot of this is redundant, but this is just for demonstration purposes
        display.loadPixels();
        for (int x = 0; x < kinect.width; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < kinect.height; y++) {

                int offset = x + y * kinect.width;
                // Raw depth
                int rawDepth = depth[offset];
                int pix = x + y * display.width;
                if (rawDepth < threshold) {
                    // A red color instead
                    display.pixels[pix] = color(150, 50, 50);
                } else {
                    display.pixels[pix] = img.pixels[offset];
                }
            }
        }
        display.updatePixels();

        // Draw the image
        image(display, 0, 0);
    }

    int getThreshold() {
        return threshold;
    }

    public void setThreshold(int t) {
        threshold =  t;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PApplet needs a couple of arguments to start. Have you supplied those?

See this page for an example: https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/

Comment: i have tried adding arguments but it doesn't seem to do anything, could you try adding arguments on this? Thank you

Comment: @chessefries No, of course I cannot do that because the arguments are specific to **you** executing the program. How did you add the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

**Why do you have two classes that extend `PApplet`?**

99.99% of the time, you should only have **one** class that extends `PApplet`. You would then pass instances of that class around to other classes in order to call Processing functions.

Unless you have a very good reason for extending `PApplet` twice, then you should probably only extend it once.

**Why don't you have a `main()` method?**

If you aren't running this from the Processing editor, then you need to write your own `main()` method to launch your code. In your `main()` method, you need to call the `PApplet.main("YourSketchClassNameHere")` function to tell Processing to start up your sketch.